# display all images which belongs to user

Tags: php, mysql

I have four table: classifieds, state, city and img.  I want to display all images which belong to a unique id(user).

For ex: A user from Minneapolis(city) Minnesota(state) posts an ad about selling a car that has 5 pictures.

I got everything working with this query, except the result is repeating user information for every image.

```
<?php
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds 
    LEFT JOIN  img ON img.classified_id = classifieds.id     
    LEFT JOIN  state ON classifieds.state_id = state.id 
     LEFT JOIN  city ON classifieds.city_id = city.id WHERE id = '".$id."'  AND  

    authorized = '1' 

   ");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
   {   
   ?>      

    <div align="center"><a href=' <?php echo $row['image_path']; ?>' rel='lightbox'  

    title='<?php echo $row['title']; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;'> <img 

   src='<?php echo $row['image_path']; ?>' width='150' border='0' />
     </a>
   </div>


   <div class="show_location" style="width:225px; hight:10px; padding-top:20px;"> 

    <span  class='style55'><?php echo $lang['D_STATE']; ?> <span style="color:#06F"> 

   <?php echo $row['statename']; ?></span> </div>

   <div style="width:225px; hight:10px; padding-top:20px;"> <?php echo 

   $lang['D_CITY']; ?><span style="color:#06F"> <?php echo $row['city']; ?></span> 

   </span> </div>

   <?php
   }
   ?>
```

I looked up for some answers in this site, and I tried to group by, but it returns only the first image.

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: use group by image_id, or image_name, something that make unique each images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'img' table has multiple records for same 'classified_id'.. so your query will produce multiple records for the same classifieds id. You have two options here

1. instead of joinig the img table in the main query, write separate query for fetching images inside the while loop.
2. Use 'group_concat' function for retrieving images.. but you have to split the concated string to image names.

Try this (first option)

```
<?php
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classifieds 
LEFT JOIN  state ON classifieds.state_id = state.id 
LEFT JOIN  city ON classifieds.city_id = city.id WHERE classifieds.id = '" . $id . "'  AND authorized = '1'");

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$get_images_query = "SELECT * FROM img WHERE classified_id = " . $row['id'];
$exec_get_images_query = mysql_query($get_images_query);
while($res_images = mysql_fetch_array($exec_get_images_query))
{   
    ?>
    <div align="center"><a href=' <?php echo $res_images['image_path']; ?>' rel='lightbox' title='<?php echo $row['title']; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;'> <img src='<?php echo $res_images['image_path']; ?>' width='150' border='0' /></a>
   </div>
   <?php
}
?>
<div class="show_location" style="width:225px; hight:10px; padding-top:20px;"><span  class='style55'><?php echo $lang['D_STATE']; ?> <span style="color:#06F"> <?php echo $row['statename']; ?></span></div>
<div style="width:225px; hight:10px; padding-top:20px;"><?php echo $lang['D_CITY']; ?><span style="color:#06F"> <?php echo $row['city']; ?></span></div>
```

Comment: I tried the first option, and returned all images in that table:           $pic = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM img
       LEFT JOIN classifieds ON  classifieds.id = img.classified_id ");  then I added GROUP BY img.classified_id and it returned one image of each ad.